# E: Signature verification failed on Sideload

Tags: android, adb, cyanogenmod, sideloading

I went into the cyanogen recover menu and did a full factory reset before upgrading to LinageOS. Now when I try to sideload a package to the phone is shows "E: Signature Verification Failed"

Also, when I type

```
adb devices
```

I get back

```
List of devices attached
1a1e7719        unauthorized
```

Any help please! There is no OS to boot to so I cannot enable/disable USB Debugging etc.

Also, when I try to adb push I get the following

```
error: device unauthorized.
This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

Answer (score 1):

---

```
List of devices attached
1a1e7719        unauthorized
```

---

This means the rsa fingerprint on your computer and the device didn't authorize the computer. This is adb failure.

1. In Developer Options > USB Debugging > Revoke Permissions
2. Turn off USB Debugging
3. Install ADB/Fastboot properly [Full article here](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/)

Windows:

1. Re install adb/fastboot [Download here][2]
2. Ensure your device drivers are recognized by the computer. Else
   download accordingly
3. Connect the device to computer and turn on USB Debugging.
4. You should some message which asks you permission to authorize and it is advisable to click on "Allow always"
5. `adb devices`
   Ubuntu:
6. Open terminal and type `sudo su`
7. `adb kill-server`
8. `adb devices`

If you're able to see your device code with a name, Et Voila.

16-10-14-04

Answer (score -1):

You find linageOS community help on reddit or help with Report bugs, find info here: https://wiki.lineageos.org/

I think you can copy the current linage os on the sd card and fresh  install it from the recovery (TWRP)? which device do you use?

And  disable zip verification in TWRP...

I use Motorola XT910, called umts_spyder.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18650878)

Comment: thanks for the note. - it is possible to report ADB logs of bugs to linage developers via Jira. info under the mentioned link.

Comment: I think you can copy the current linage os on the sd card and install it from the recovery (TWRP)? which device do you use?

Comment: how does one "disable zip verification in TWRP" ?